# Extract dictionary definition of word from text file with mutiline content

Tags: regex, perl

I have the text formatted dictionary from which I would like to extract
only the multi-line definition of word while ignoring other single line noise.
Is it possible to do that?
Below is the example for word Absolve. I would like to see only 6th paragraph

```
   Absolutory (a.) Serving to absolve; absolving.

   Absolvable (a.) That may be absolved.

   Absolvatory (a.) Conferring absolution; absolutory.

   Absolved (imp. & p. p.) of Absolve

   Absolving (p. pr. & vb. n.) of Absolve

   Absolve (v. t.) To set free, or release, as from some obligation, debt,
   or responsibility, or from the consequences of guilt or such ties as it
   would be sin or guilt to violate; to pronounce free; as, to absolve a
   subject from his allegiance; to absolve an offender, which amounts to
   an acquittal and remission of his punishment.

   Absolve (v. t.) To free from a penalty; to pardon; to remit (a sin); --
   said of the sin or guilt.

   Absolve (v. t.) To finish; to accomplish.

   Absolve (v. t.) To resolve or explain.

   Absolvent (a.) Absolving.

   Absolvent (n.) An absolver.
```

Comment: Why would you not choose the 7th paragraph? It is also multiline

Comment: Yes 7th paragraph can be included since it may contain alternate usage/definition of the word,  but let's stick to one that contains extensive definition i.e. most lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can extract the definition with the longest string length:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'dict.txt';
my $word = 'Absolve';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
my @lines = split /\s*\n(?:\s*\n)+/, $str;
my @candidates;
for my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ /^\s*\Q$word\E\s/) {
        push @candidates, $line;
    }
}
if (@candidates) {
    @candidates = sort { length $b <=> length $a } @candidates;
    say $candidates[0];  # <-- first item has the longest length
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I am now using words from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt with your solution to clean-up my searchable text dictionary.